# WSO2 ESB BAM integration

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

I have installed the BAM 2.0.0, ESB 4.5.0 and AS 5.0.0 on my environment. I would like to watch service statistics. So i have installed the BAM agent on AS and ESB. However i could only see the AS service statistics on BAM. How could i see the service statistics of ESB on BAM.

Thanks,

PS : These are the steps i have followed for the configuration.First i have installed the BAM agent on AS and ESB ( http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Setting+up+Service+Statistics+Data+Agent) then i have configured the the toolbox on BAM (http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Service+Statistics+Toolbox). I am able to see the AS service statistics on BAM however i could not see the ESB statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BAM 2.0.0 doesn't have dashboard for showing proxy/sequence/endpoint statistics. This dashboard comes with next release. But data will publish to BAM side from Mediation data agent. So If you are familiar with Hive and UI works, you can implement your own dashboard too.

Comment: Thanks Kashun, But i am trying echo service on both as and esb, and as far as i know this is not proxy service. So i think i should see at least some information on default BAM cassandra DB. However i could only see the AS logs on EVENT_KS column family.

Comment: Thanks Kasun, You were right. ESB mediation agent is working as you said.